# Web service that serves as public proof that a given url contains something at a given time

Tags: web-apps, scraping

I did something "amazing" on a website and my narcissistic side wants proof for posterity that I managed to actually do it, even if the website in question decides to change it's rules or goes off-line.

For example, what inspired me to ask this question was 100 year long streak on GitHub https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099235/who-is-the-user-with-the-longest-streak-on-github/27742165 which could disappear without proof at any time since GitHub usually simply makes smaller modifications to their back-end without informing anyone. And screenshots that I upload myself are obviously trivial to falsify.

But I can see this having more serious applications, like serving as legal evidence that is simpler than subpoenaing server logs, or when those are inaccessible (e.g. foreign country). Although [it has already been declined in court once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine#Use_in_legal_evidence).

If only there was a web service, in which I input an URL, click a button, and then it would immediately:

- fetch the HTML and all of its dependencies
- make the original webpage viewable on a public URL of the mirroring website. Storing a screenshot only instead of the original HTML would be acceptable, but not ideal.
- associate a timestamp and an URL to it, **in a way that I couldn't change it** afterwards. E.g., it could encode that information in the URL as `http://snapshot.com/view/2015-01-01/http://github.com`, or simply add a custom header

Non-mandatory features that would be nice:

- Authentication. Not sure if technically feasible.
- send an arbitrary HTTP request instead of just a simple GET
- retrieve other media types HTML, in special PDF. archive.org [does this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150414083806/http://www.cirosantilli.com/files/cv.pdf).
- ignore `robots.txt` when I do a manual request. It's not cool to *crawl* those websites, but I don't see why not take a snapshot on request, which is just like me loading the page. Original motivation: prove that a website was at position N on a Google search: https://web.archive.org/web/https://www.google.com/search?q=x86+paging+tutorial archive.is currently does this: https://archive.is/vkc8B
- archive the page even if it gives 500. Can be used as proof that I've found a bug. archive.org does not seem to do this.

Of course, the entire system would hinge on the belief that of the web service in question is not cheating, which although not ideal, is acceptable to me.

What I have found so far:

- Wayback machine: http://archive.org/web/ . If only there was a button that I could press to generate a snapshot whenever I want it, it would solve my problem
- many websites that take a URL and convert it into an image, but none that stores the image on their server and assigns a timestamp and origin URL to it

Comment: Does http://archive.org meet your requirements?

Comment: @Pacerier as mentioned in the question, AFAIK no because I could not find a button to take a snapshot whenever I want

Comment: @Circo, What about http://archive.is ? There's some suggestions at http://alternativeto.net/software/wayback-machine/ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_archiving_initiatives, https://www.quora.com/Aside-from-the-Wayback-Machine-what-are-other-options-for-getting-screenshots-of-websites-from-the-past too.

Comment: @Pacerier that worked. I have tested it and added a little info. Answered as a community wiki so I won't get rep on your back. Please answer directly next time with such good suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: @Pacerier An alternative is you also answer and get your repz :)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功, The rep belongs to you. I've just pointed to the links, [didn't made any evaluation](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/329/356).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [icanprove.com](http://www.icanprove.net) might fit your needs.

The screenshots are not presented online. They are stored in signed pdfs so you have to upload them themselves but on the other hand this gives you more control.

It offers a virtual remote browser (an old Firefox version) inside your browser which allows you to authenticate into websites. You have of course to trust that service with your passwords. Note that there is some delay between pressing the keystrokes and them taking effect on the remote browser, but it's usable.

Comment: This is cool. Do you understand how their signature method works?

Comment: To see the signature you have to open the pdfs with Adobe Reader (not the plugin). To make Adobe "accept" the signature you have to configure it to trust your operation system's certificates.

Comment: It seems that there is no free implementation for verifying PDFs under Linux? http://askubuntu.com/questions/226257/how-can-i-validate-a-pdfs-digital-signature-with-evince Adobe describes the method at: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf , standard PKI + RSA / DSA.

Comment: @MartinLoehnertz, Any disclaimers?

Comment: As this still is somewhat experimental - many disclaimers -> see disclaimers :-). Investors that could provide the needed legal muscle still have not shown up (despite some pitches). But I still am confident that it is only a question of patience.

Answer (score 4):

After grepping the [archive.org FAQ](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php) just found that it *does* have a "Save page now" box under https://archive.org/web/ ...

I found this after noting that if a page had not been crawled when you search for it, it suggests: "Do you want to take a snapshot now?"

This makes it the best option so far, as it also has one of the optional operations: PDF save, and feels more future-proof than `archive.today`. [Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150419212121/http://www.cirosantilli.com/files/cv.pdf).

Comment: Also on http://lifehacker.com/manually-archive-web-pages-by-submitting-them-to-the-wa-1580713309

Comment: Argh, I found out that it has a limitation. It ignores everything after `#`, so if a page displays differently based on the value of the characters after `#`, archive.org wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Parcier, archive.is does what I want.

It stores both screenshot and HTML, and says the date.

E.g. snapshot I just took from GitHub: https://archive.today/eN836

Does not seem to have any of the non-mandatory features.

The creator said in march 2015 that they don't do authentication: http://blog.archive.today/post/114635965191/you-should-allow-users-to-send-cookie-strings-to he then points to http://www.peeep.us/ but it looks dead.

I could not find request customization either, and PDF tests failed for me.

For relevant lists, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_archiving_initiatives and http://alternativeto.net/software/archive-is/